# Java 8 closures and type recognition

Tags: java, closures

I'm testing the new closure features of Java 8; I'm wondering why this piece of code

```
public class Test8 {
    private class A { int a;}
    private class B { int b;}    
    interface IFA { void ifa(A param); }
    interface IFB { void ifb(B param); }
    private void forceA(A expr) {  }    
    private void z(IFA fun) { System.out.println( "A"); fun.ifa( new A() ); }
    private void z(IFB fun) { System.out.println( "B"); fun.ifb( new B() ); }    

    public void run() {
        z( x -> forceA(x) );
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {   new Test8().run(); }
}
```

gives the error:  `both method z(IFA) in Test8 and method z(IFB) in Test8 match error` on z invocation in the run method

Isn't the compiler able to detect that the `forceA` invocation forces x to be of type A and thus the correct z to use is `z(IFA fun)` ?

(a similar function is legal in C# using delegate; is there a way to get the same result in Java 8? )

Comment: If this doesn't compile, then the compiler clearly isn't smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 is still a work in progress. The latest spec does allow your code to work. The compiler implementation should catch up soon.

Nevertheless, this kind of overloading is not a good style. We have signatures

```
    z( A->void )
    z( B->void )
```

then when javac sees

```
    z( arg->{ block } )
```

it's not apparent which `z()` applies. Extra work must be done (by compiling block) to pick one.

We don't really care about how difficult it is to javac. The real issue is, when a human sees that code, the human has to dig deeper to understand which `z()` is referred to. Not very readable.

As a rule of thumb, avoid overloading a method with functional interfaces of the same arity. Different arities are fine, there's no problem to disambiguate, for human or javac

```
    z( arg->{...} )

    z( (arg1,arg2)->{...} )
```

Another form of overloading is also blessed by the designers (Dan Smith etc) - same arity, same parameter types, but different return types

```
    z( X->R1 )
    z( X->R2 )
```

but I think it is pretty confusing too and I would avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with the new version of the compiler as soon as it is published. I know that it is not a good style, but I was only testing the language (closure) capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the lambda is not used to determine its type. Like methods. I guess a method reference may work. But euw, overloading.